# How can I select a random place on a canvas object with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, canvas, xpath

I am using Java Selenium for making automated tests on a cinema site
When I select the movie,I want to select the places for the movie
Then I have a canvas object and I don't know hot to select a random place for the movie
Here is the code from the table:

```
   <div class="seatplanControl">
   <div class="screen">
   <div id="SeatPlanContainer" style="direction:ltr;">
      <div id="panzoom-parent" style="padding: 0px; height: 464.25px; width: 
                       761.508px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
         <canvas id="myCanvas" class="panzoom" style="background-color: 
               rgb(212, 212, 212); touch-action: pan-y; -moz-user-select: 
               none; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2.325); transform-
               origin: 50% 50% 0px; cursor: pointer; transition: none 0s ease 
               0s ;" height="475" width="787"/>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Can you please help me with a code for this situation?
In this moment am I using this solution:

```
     WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/div/canvas[@id='myCanvas']")); 
     Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
     builder.moveToElement(element, 10, 25).click().build().perform();`
```

but it doesn't work every time because when a random movie is selected,I am receiving different cordonates for canvas object

```
`
```

Comment: How did you get `10, 25` as in `moveToElement(element, 10, 25)`

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: It's obviously a question, a request for clarification on how you got the "magic" numbers that you're using.

Comment: I used random numbers because I don't know exactly how to work with this canvas object
Sometimes it works with this cordonates sometimes it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

You have identify the co-ordinates bases on webelement.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/div/canvas[@id='myCanvas']")); 
 Point point = element.getLocation();
 int xcord = point.getX();
 int ycord = point.getY();
 Actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
 builder.moveToElement(element, xcord, ycord).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: I've tried your solutions but it doesn't work
I am receiving this error
       org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: (1055.3500061035156, 814) is out of bounds of viewport width (1270) and height (688)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989076/how-to-handle-movetargetoutofboundsexception-in-selenium-webdriver , this might help you